# jest.fn() not recognized by expect as a spy function?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, expect.js

**Error:**

> The "actual" argument in expect(actual).toHaveBeenCalled() must be a spy

**Minimal not-working example:**

```
const mockFn = jest.fn();
mockFn();
expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

**Question:** is `jest.fn()` not a spy?

Comment: Your example works fine: https://repl.it/J8WG/0. Why you mention `expect.js` in your tags, do you use it? Cause Jest comes with its own, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle you are right. My `expect` is actually from `expect.js` which caused the problem.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle This solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below implementation which worked for me,

```
it("should call mock function when button is clicked", () => {
    const mockFn = jest.fn();
    const tree = shallow(<button name="button test" handleHandler={mockFn} />);
    tree.simulate("click");
    mockFn();
    expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Hey, I have a question, why did you call `mockFn();` before the expect statement?